# How to change new mongodb.ObjectId so it works again

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios

Since this mongodb change

```
let  MongoClient  = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

this is not working anymore

```
_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)
```

```
 app.post("/update-item", function(req, res) {
    db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate(
       {_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)}, 
       {$set: {text: req.body.text}
    }, 
    res.send('Success'))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change _id as your defined req.body.id

```
app.post("/update-item", function(req, res) { db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {$set: {text: req.body.text}}, res.send('Success')) })
```

You can set initially _id as "1234" or anything you wished for